# Populate a JComboBox with an ArrayList from a different class

Tags: java

I'm currently stuck in this part of a class project... I need to create an ArrayList from a text file; text file has account numbers that need to be populated in a JComboBox. This is what I have so far... only the first account number populates missing the rest not sure what my mistake is

```
//   AccountUtility class that reads file and creates ArrayList named test

public class AccountUtility {

    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] number;
    String columns[], accountNumber, customerName, openDate, balance;
    int size;


public AccountUtility(){


    BufferedReader in = null;
    try{    // assume products.txt already exists
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accounts.txt"));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while(line != null)  {
    columns = line.split("<>");
    accountNumber = columns[0];
    customerName = columns[1];
    openDate = columns[2];
    balance = columns[3];

                    line = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
            System.out.println(ioe);
    }
} 

 public ArrayList <String>  getAccountNumbers( ){

     ArrayList <String>  test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add(accountNumber);

     return test;




//class  with JComboBox (GUI)

public class BankAccountApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public BankAccountApp() {

        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        AccountUtility gc = new AccountUtility();

        for( String numbers : gc.getAccountNumbers()){ 
        accountNumberComboBox.addItem(numbers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't perform operations in the constructor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that what you want is

```
while(line != null)  {
    columns = line.split("<>");
    accountNumber = columns[0];
    test.add(accountNumber);
    ....
}
```

and

```
public ArrayList getAccountNumbers( ){
   return test;
}
```

Comment: If this answer was useful please consider to upvote and/or accept.